# Is there a Tiny Well-Known Binary (TWKB) implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, format, well-known-binary, twkb

I am aware of https://github.com/TWKB/twkb.js and I'm looking at evaluating [Tiny Well-Known Binary](https://github.com/TWKB/Specification) (TWKB) in a `c#` application.  I did some googling but came up empty.

Are there any efforts underway to implement this in c#?